# Needed Customized Auto_generated id -> In NestJs with Mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nestjs

Like : GM22JA001 (company identifier+year+Month+3Digit num)

Output:
GM22JA001
GM22JA002
GM22JA003

Comment: Trigger + additional table.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What do you use for June/July?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Adding employee in db. for that I need customized and auto generated Id number. and, JN for June and JL for July. Hope you understand